# How do a check previous a test execution in jUnit 5?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, boot

I need do a validation before execute many test's in a Spring Boot app, with jUnit 5. Basically I need check if my test have a superclass (because we preload context there). I dont want to edit every test else do something that allows me to check before running each test. I did something like this:

```
public class InheritClassTestCheckExtension implements TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider, BeforeEachCallback {

@Override
public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    Class<?> superClass = context.getRequiredTestClass().getSuperclass();
    String listClasses = "";
    if (superClass doesnt exists or is object, throw a exception) {
        throw new Exception("Need to inherit from class A,B or C");
   } else { 
       Continue to the test's
   }
}
```

I have this in my junit-platform.properties

```
junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.names=com.my.package.InheritClassTestCheckExtension
```

But this doesnt work (It's not even entering the method beforeEach). I'm in the correct way? Or what can I use to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled` flag works for the extentions  registered via ServiceLoader mechanism
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic-enabling

So, it's expected having the `InheritClassTestCheckExtension` full class name
in `META-INF/services/org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension` file

---

Alternativaly, it's possible using explicit declaration with [`@ExtendWith`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative) or  [`@RegisterExtension`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic) annotations,